# Can healers get end game card for eliminations?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch usually gives you [end game card](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Card) according to your role. Like Solder gets a card for damage done, Reinhard gets a card for damage shielded, Tracer can get a card for number of recalls.
I wonder if Mercy (and other healers) can get a card for gold eliminations/damage or algorithm just won't count them, since it is not her job?

Comment: They can, it's just unlikely, since when elimination cards are given out it's looking for a much higher performance. Like if gold elims is 30 and the next closest for either team is 15-20. It's all compared to other players in the game, not just purely having the medal. I've gotten gold elims and the card as symmetra before, but she's technically not a healer like you asked about. Also there's this question already: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271681/end-game-card-priority-how-does-it-work?rq=1

Comment: I've had a single game (out of a lot) where I managed a 5-gold as Zenyatta.  If I recall right I did get a card for it, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They absolutely can. However, it's *extremely* unlikely unless both teams are pants-on-head awful and the healer is spending their time attacking instead of healing. The reason it requires both teams to do badly is because not only do you have to beat out your own team's DPS, you also have to do more damage than the other team's highest damage source - by an amount significant enough that the card system decides to show your card.

This is actually easiest to accomplish with Zenyatta, since he has the highest potential DPS of any support. I have been able to do this once, at a very low level when new players didn't know what they were doing. I have not been able to do it since, nor have I seen it done by other people since the earliest levels.

Comment: So what exactly have you got on Zenyatta, elims or dmg?

Comment: I believe it was damage at the time, but it was a long time ago (pretty much on release) so I don't remember exactly. I just remember thinking it seemed  a little weird that a support had the highest damage/kills/whatever the offensive stat was.

Comment: Ok. I did it. :D https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8L0T.jpg